# How to install Geo Pandas package in Jupyter Notebook in Python ? All solutions do not work

Tags: python, pandas, installation, geopandas

How to install geopandas, I really tried everything and I still has error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'`. I have the latest version of Python 3.9.6. I use Windows 10, I use Anaconda Prompt, I have only one version of Python.

I do not want to create other environment, I want to install it as any other package, how to do it? I tried:

```
pip install geopandas 

conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas

!conda install geopandas
```

I checked also this page: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html to find solution but I still do not have this package. But package folium was installed correctly by pip install folium.

Help me because I try to do in second day in a row ;/

Comment: We need way more information. What base env are you running? Do you have multiple versions of python installed? Are you on windows, linux, mac, etc.? Are in installing in the terminal or Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: I use Windows 10, I use Anaconda Prompt, I have only one version of Python and it is 2.9.6 (the latest) :)

Comment: From a cell in a notebook what do these two lines of code return? `import sys` and then   
`!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user geopandas`

Comment: Can you try `!pip install geopandas`?

Comment: MDR your two liner returned error: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: it is really long error

Comment: Suneesh in case of your solution in anaconda prompt I have error: '!pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: MDR moreover there are many things about Fiona

Comment: Does anyone knows how to install it ?

Answer (score 2):

I will transcribe here the solution I found; all glory goes to Mr. Tanish Gupta, long life to him. Source [here :)](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fastest-way-to-install-geopandas-in-jupyter-notebook-on-windows-8f734e11fa2b). I hope it helps!

I did this in my win10 PC, I have Anaconda 2.1.4 and only the Python version which comes with it (3.7 I believe). I use Anaconda Prompt, I have only that one version of Python ('cause I had the latest Py ver, but outside Anaconda, and tried [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-installation-the-easy-way-for-windows-31a666b3610f). It worked, but for that 3.10 Python version, not for the Jupyter Py ver, if that makes sense).

To my understanding, probably there is some incompatibility between the libraries installed in the base environment, so we'll be creating a new one.

1. In the Anaconda command prompt, create a new environment variable:
   `conda create -n geo_env`
2. Activate this environment “geo_env”, then add and set conda-forge channel:

   `conda create -n geo_env`

   `conda config  --env --add channels conda-forge`

   `conda config --env --set channel_priority strict`
3. Install Geopandas in the environment just created:
   `conda install geopandas`
4. Next install Jupyter notebook in this environment:
   `conda install jupyter notebook`

   Note: If the above command doesn’t work for you, try `conda install notebook`.
5. Now add our environment to Jupyter notebook:
   `python -m ipykernel install --name geo_env`
6. Change to our new environment in the AnacondaNavigator. Enjoy :D

In my case, then I had issues with seaborn and wordcloud in this environment, so I tried installing C++, 'cause it said in the error output, you know, I just wanted more headaches (it didn't work). Finally I installed them in the same way explained before and everything ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you're either having a conflict between channels or you forgot to install geopandas packages when doing it with pip.

First of all, in an anaconda prompt, start by cleaning your environment by removing the packages that got installed by pip.
To do so just `pip uninstall geopandas fiona pyproj rtree shapely`.
Once you're done with that, run a `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` (normally should work).